# Convert Excel Formula to VBA - Count Upper Case Characters in a String

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, type-conversion

=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$7) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$7, CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))), "")))

This formula above counts the Upper Case Characters in a string.  It works great.  I can not seem to get it converted to VBA.  I am substituting Application.WorksheetFunction where needed and I have made use of double-quotes for the indirect function.

(My Effort)
MyCaps =Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$7) - LEN(Application.WorksheetFunction.SUBSTITUTE($A$7, CHAR(Application.WorksheetFunction.ROW(INDIRECT(""65:90""))), "")))

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a worksheet function in your code instead of writing a function to check for the upper-case letters and return the count?

Comment: no - just lazy :)  and curios and why the WS function wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you don't need to use `INDIRECT()` at all with your formula in your worksheets. `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$7,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),"")))` works because of `SUMPRODUCT()`. Not sure why 'the internet' want to use `INDIRECT()` when you search for this. And, if you must, make the range of rows absolute `$65:$90` and ready for dragging.

Translate this to VBA would be along the lines of:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "ABCd"

Debug.Print Evaluate(Replace("=SUM(LEN(""X"")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(""X"",CHAR(ROW(65:90)),"""")))", "X", s))
Debug.Print Evaluate("=SUM(LEN(""" & s & """)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(""" & s & """,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),"""")))") 'Either of the two.

End Sub
```

**Note:** `Evaluate` will auto-CSE the formula for you. Hence `SUM()` instead of `SUMPRODUCT()`.

**Note:** If you are set on using `A7` then be sure to be explicit about which worksheet you are working from. By default `Evaluate` will refer to the then active sheet. E.g.:

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=SUM(LEN(A7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A7,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),"""")))")
```

Comment: thank you - perfect on both versions.   You made me curious about the internet fetish for Indirect.

Comment: =SMALL(FIND(0,SUBSTITUTE(A7,CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),0)&0),3)   This is the second half of the same problem.  I am still getting stuck trying to get rid of Indirect in these problems.  The equation above gives the position in a sting of the 3rd Upper Case character ( that is the trailing "3") in the last of the equation.  I can't get it to function inside VBA.  I have written a loop that solves the problem, but I would really like to understand these formula conversion issues.

Comment: Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=SMALL(FIND(0,SUBSTITUTE(A7,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),0)&0),3)")  This works in VBA.  Thanks again for your help